# Why am I getting JSX element must have parent element?

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I checked to see if everything is wrapped in my code about 100 times and I cannot find out why that error is showing up.

Here is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
          {Jobs.map((item) => (
        <div className="card-image"></div>
        <div className="card-text">
          <span className="date">{item.date}</span>
          <h2>{item.Job}</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>{item.description}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
          ))
  }
        </div>
    )

        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add a wrapper element to your map return, as that is currently returning multiple elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning more than one element from .map. You need to wrap both the elements within a `React.Fragment` or `<>`

```js
render(){
    return (
        <div className="card">
            {Jobs.map((item) => (
                <>
                <div className="card-image"></div>
                <div className="card-text">
                    <span className="date">{item.date}</span>
                    <h2>{item.Job}</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{item.description}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </>
          ))}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `}` at the end.

Try:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
          {Jobs.map((item) => (
           <div className="card-image"></div>
           <div className="card-text">
             <span className="date">{item.date}</span>
             <h2>{item.Job}</h2>
             <ul>
               <li>{item.description}</li>
             </ul>
           </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: That is just lazy part from OP, issue is with multiple elements return in .map.